# VB default of Procedure and module, public or private?

Tags: vb6, module

is the default of procedure and module public or private?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**In both VB.NET and VB 6, both methods/procedures and classes/modules default to `Public`.** That means if you don't specify a particular access level, they will always be public. So this:

```
Sub SetName(ByVal name As String)
    'do work here
End Sub
```

is equivalent to this:

```
Public Sub SetName(ByVal name As String)
    'do work here
End Sub
```

For VB.NET, see this handy chart for more details: [Declaration Contexts and Default Access Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235296%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**However, I *highly recommend* that you never rely on the default scope.** Always explicitly specify an access level for your classes/modules as well as methods/procedures. The defaults can vary across languages, so another programmer looking at your code might not guess correctly, and it's always better to err on the side of expressiveness.

Also, keep in mind that most things should be `Private` anyway. If you don't explicitly need something to have public scope, you should declare it as `Private`. This increases modularity in your code and prevents accidental access from another unrelated section of code.

Comment: Are variables and properties also `Public` by default in VB6?  Does this mean that even in VB6, they are exposed outside the assembly by default?

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net Module statement defaults to Friend, not Public. Regards

Comment: Do you have a source? If this is the case then the accepted answer is not correct and this should be accepted instead.